# Add directory and file information to email

Tags: powershell

After changing an alert so it now only collects information when a file is a certain age - the email that is generated is now very basic

I'm looking to add the directory information as the previous email had.

```
    function send_email  {
    $loop = 0
    # try repeat send email when it fails
    while ($loop -lt 5)   {

        # -BodyAsHtml
        Send-MailMessage -From $mail_from -To $mail_to -Subject "$subj" -Body "$body" -SmtpServer "$smtp_host"

        if ($?)  {
            Write-Host "Email sent successfully."
            $loop = 99999;
        } else  {
            $loop++
            Write-Host "Error: Failed to send email ($loop), retrying..."
            sleep 30
        }
    }
}

    #folders to check
    [string[]]$folders = Get-Content -Path ($cwd + 'test.txt')

$refDate = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)
$body = foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    Write-Host "Checking $folder"
    # gather a list of files older than 30 minutes ago
    $lst = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate })
    if ($lst.Count) {
        
        $lst.FullName
    }
}

$body

if (@($body).Count) {
    send_email
}
```

generates the below (please also note, if the path is short enough, two paths will show on one line):

[image: New details]

Whereas the previous email had the following information, with the filename below:

[image: Old details]

What code is required to be added above to make the output email in a similar format?

I don't really care about Mode, but having the filename below the directory is better to see (and navigate by clicking the folder path), but the LastWrite time is really important

Comment: So basically you are asking us to rewrite your function `send_email` which you do not show...

Comment: @Theo Well the `send_email` function is the same in both scripts so I assumed the issue is here, which is the only part that changed

Comment: Then I guess you want `$lst | Out-String` instead of `$lst.FullName` ?